# Sybase Dropping Temporary Table

Tags: temp-tables, sap-ase

Does anybody face an issue when you drop a temporary table at the Sybase ASE 12 it still persists at a current session. So you encounter "Table already exists" when trying to select data into it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to read the manuals, at least the syntax for the commands you expect to use, before you write code.  Otherwise you will face issues at every turn.  It depends on what you are trying to do.

1. `SELECT ... INTO #MyTable` creates a table and succeeds because it does not exist. So a second `SELECT ... INTO #MyTable` will try to create `#MyTable`, find that it exists, and fail.
2. If you want to perform a second `SELECT` into the same table, `TRUNCATE` the table, then use `SELECT ... INTO EXISTING TABLE #MyTable`.
3. Or `DROP TABLE` and skip the `EXISTING TABLE` modifier.
4. If you want the table to contain the sum of several `SELECTS`, obviously, skip the `TRUNCATE`.

Comment: Thank you, I found out that one had to SELECT INTO #Tmp at another batch after DROP TABLE #Tmp to succeed.

Comment: @Luke. Temp tables are exactly that, for the session.  If you go outside the session, you run into weird problems.  If you need a temp table that is accessible from different batches or sessions, use the `tempdb..table_name` form not the `#table` form.

Answer (score 1):

I normally do this:

1) CREATE TABLE #temptable (
....

)

INSERT INTO #temptable
SELECT .....

This will never give error.

This solves another possible error . If the WHERE clause accompanying the "select INTO  "  yields no rows, the temporary table will not have zero rows but the temporary table won't be created at all.  This could make the stored proc blow up later.